# GCSFuse not finding default credentials when running a cloud run app docker locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, gcsfuse

I am working on mounting a Cloud Storage Bucket to my Cloud Run App, using the example and code from the official tutorial https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse

The application uses docker only (no cloudbuild.yaml)

The docker file compiles with out issue using command:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t fusemount .
```

I then start docker run with the following command

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 fusemount
```

and when run gcsfuse is triggered with both the directory endpoint and the bitbucket URL

```
gcsfuse --debug_gcs --debug_fuse gs://<my-bucket> /mnt/gs
```

But the connection fails:

> 022/12/11 13:54:35.325717 Start gcsfuse/0.41.9 (Go version go1.18.4)
> for app "" using mount point: /mnt/gcs 2022/12/11 13:54:35.618704
> Opening GCS connection...
> 2022/12/11 13:57:26.708666 Failed to open connection: GetTokenSource:
> DefaultTokenSource: **google: could not find default credentials**. See
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
> for more information.

I have already set up the application-defaut credentials with the following command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

and I have a python based cloud function project that I have tested on the same local machine which has no problem accessing the same storage bucket with the same default login credentials.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google libraries search for `~/.config/gcloud` when using APPLICATION_DEFAULT authorization approach.
Your local Docker container doesn't contain this config when running locally.

So, you might want to mount it when running a container:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -v /home/$USER/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 fusemount
```

Some notes:

1. I'm not sure which OS you are using, so that replace `/home/$USER` with a real path to your home
2. Same, I'm not sure your image has `/root` home, so make sure that path from 1. is mounted properly
3. Make sure your local user is authorized to gcloud cli, as you mentioned, using this command `gcloud auth application-default login`

Let me know, if this helped.

Comment: This put me on the right path.  I am running on Mac OSX. I modified the command a little and found the worked - docker run --rm -v ~/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 fusemount

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using docker and not using Google Compute engine (GCE), did you try mounting service account key when running container and using that key while mounting GCSFuse ?
- If you are building and deploying to Cloud run, did you grant required permissions mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse#ship-code?